# How can my C# application use a portable database with no installation or configuration

Tags: c#, database, database-connection

I am developing a MVVM WPF application that requires storing large amounts of relational data. I would like to use a database platform, as it will simplify the task and the resulting software would be more robust. There are concerns, however that the users will not be able to install or configure a database.

`Are there any options that allow a database to be used, but also created and configured automatically by the application? Are there any that can be 'hidden' inside the application's resources so they cannot be accessed directly?`

I am storing location data. Each record has a time of occurrence, and an x and y coordinate. A Tag can have many records of location data, along with custom data items that can be added by the user. The database would likely have 5 tables at the most. Is a database the right choice, or should I really be creating and loading custom files into the MVVM WPF application? I'm really not experienced with managing all of these file operations, creating directories so they can be used in the application and I feel that I can build a much better application using a database. Are there any resources relating to what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF you want to use a database take a look at [SqlCompact](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876) or [SqLite](http://sqlite.org/)

Both of these allow you to store relational data and embed the database engine into your application.

Shameless plus: [SauceDB](https://github.com/iamkrillin/SauceDB) also supports both of these.